# Why is example number not shown automatically according to Chapter number?

Tags: numbering, examples

I used `\begin{example}` to create examples. And it produce Example. But it did not show any example no. When I set counter it shows no. for eg: Example. 13. Can example no. comes automatically according to chapter no?.

```
  \documentclass{report}
\usepacke{amsmath}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\newcounter{example}
\addtocounter{example}{10}
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip
\textbf{Example~\theexample. #1} \rmfamily}{\medskip}
\rmfamily}{\medskip}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{11}
\chapter{Footing Design}
\section{Numerical Examples}
\refstepcounter{example}

\begin{example}
  Design of footng.
\end{example}

\begin{example}
  Individual footing example.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example contains some syntax errors and is not compilable at all (as of now) -- and there are better ways to achieve this, in my point of view

Comment: Do you want to have the examples numbered like `12.1`, `12.2` etc? Otherwise the example number would be the same for all in the same chapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\newcounter{example}[chapter]
\counterwithin{example}{chapter} % Change the format to chapter number.example number


\newenvironment{example}[1][]{%
  \noindent%
  \refstepcounter{example}%
  \textbf{Example~\theexample. #1}%
}{\par\medskip}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{11}
\chapter{Footing Design}
\section{Numerical Examples}
\begin{example}
  Design of footing. 

  And now for something completely different
\end{example}
\begin{example}
  Individual footing example.
\end{example}

\chapter{Another chapter}

\begin{example}
Another example
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: Right -- it's a relict ;-)